# How to detect tabs change URLs or tabs create on Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a question about writing Google Chrome Extension. My goal now is to detect that if a tab is created or a URL of a tab has been changed.

Practically, I want to insert a dictionary .js from a link online to any webpage on Chrome, and the script will run as background.html. For example, if you open the browser and go to your homepage, it will run the script to insert dictionary.js into that page. When a new tab is created or a new page is open, it will run the script too. And when people change tab's url, it will run the script too. How do I detect if the tab changes in such situations? Ok, here is my ... code, i guess, to explain that.

```
chrome.someFunctionThatDetectTheSituationsAbove(function() {
    insertDictionaryScript();//I'd love to have the script of detection, not the insertDictionaryScript();
}
```

I would appreciate for any idea. Thank you. :P.

[x]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are describing is called a content script. You don't need any coding for that, just make a declaration in the manifest file. More about content scripts [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You got me wrong, I think. Because I use <all_urls> for the manifest file, but it works only one time when the extension starts. Ok, for example, I would `alert("HELLO!");` in the background.html. So whenever I turn the extension on, it alerts "Hello". But when you change the page URL, or open new tabs...it won't run again. So how do I detect those situations where the tab urls are changed, or new tabs are created... [x]

Comment: @xx3004 You don't need background page for this, just declare your dictionary.js as a content script in the manifest and it will be automatically included when new tab is created, url is changed, etc.

Comment: Got you, I shouldn't have put it in background.html. Thank you very much! [x]

Comment: @serg It would have worked if Chrome allowed me to specify [CSS Origin](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extensionTypes/#type-CSSOrigin), as "user origin" but I think there is no way to declare this in the manifest is it? Hence, I have to use `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` for it?

Answer (score 69):

Just add this on your background.js :

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    insertDictionaryScript();
});

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {         
   insertDictionaryScript();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Very clearly! I think I know what to do now. [x]

Comment: The on Updated run many times when ever content of web is update.

Comment: @vanduc1102 - you can check if the url changed, e.g. `if (changeInfo.url) myFunc();`

Answer (score 15):

There's also **onActivated** event:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   insertDictionaryScript();
});
```

Comment: The `onActivated` callback signature is incorrect - it now takes a single object. See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated

Comment: @vaughan the link is broken

Comment: this event is completely unrelated to the question

Answer (score 4):

You can detect new tab creation by adding a listener to the [onCreated](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onCreated) event.

You can detect the url change of the tab by adding a listener to the [onUpdated](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I should use the content script declaration. But this maybe useful for some other thing :P. Again, thank you. [x]

Answer (score 3):

To detect the tab change in google chrome extensions:

In your background script.js add the below code:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function() { 
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        var currentURL = tabs[0].url;
        console.log(currentURL); 
    })
});
```